# Is Eved Ivri obligated in honoring one's parents?

Tags: women, kibbud-av-veim-honoring, slave-serve-eved-avadim

A tough question that I could not find anyone mentioning.

The Gemmorah in [Kiddushin 30b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kiddushin.30b.17?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says a married woman is exempt from honoring the parents as
"*whereas with regard to a woman, it is not in her power to perform [this Mitzva], because she is under the authority of another person [i.e. her husband, as she is obligated to her husband to maintain her household]*"

Is this condition (of marriage) more severe or lenient than Eved Ivri to exempt the later from honoring his parents?